Pystring_fromString alternative in python3
I am trying to convert my existing Python 3 code from Python 2.
The higher Level call is from GoLang,  which uses Cypython to invoke Python.
We have extensively used Python, pystring_fromstring, method. Now that method is not there in Python 3.
I have tried pyunicode from the string pybytesfromstring, but when I try to print them I get the output in byte/unicode format.
End Goal:
Its to have a python string object which is created in go.

Check the release infos for replacements to removed functions. That said, what is this "byte/unicode format"? What were you expecting? How do you determine that "it works"?
